# How do I derive the eigenvalues of the 1D Heisenberg model? (Bethe Ansatz)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin, linear-algebra

I've been trying to work through [Introduction to the Bethe Ansatz I](http://www.phys.uri.edu/gerhard/MSS/ms82.pdf#page=2) (by Michael Karbach and Gerhard Muller) in  spare time and I am having trouble deriving the eigenvalues given in equation (5) for the r=1 (1 spin down) block of the Hamiltonian.
The Hamiltonian is :
$$H=-J\sum_{n=1}^N \left[\frac{1}{2}\left(S_n^+S_{n+1}^-+S_n^-S_{n+1}^+\right)+S_n^zS_{n+1}^z\right]$$
The eigenvalues I should arrive at are:
$$E-E_o=J(1-\cos(k)) \phantom{XXXX}  (5)$$
With eigenvectors: 
$$| \psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{ikn}|n\rangle \phantom{XXXXX} (4)$$

Where $E_o$ is the energy of the state in which all spin are aligned and E is the energy of a state with one flipped spin at site n. (The lattice spacing here is 1)

All the necessary information to solve the problem appears to be given in the preceding paragraphs of the paper I linked but I have been unable to put it all together. I'm working on the second part of question 1 in the document and I have to "show that the states (4) are eigenvectors 
of H with eigenvalues (5).

Comment: Could you be more precise *what* you're not sure about?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Edited the end of the question and added numbering to the equations. I'm a bit rusty and would appreciate a step by step derivation.

Comment: @Julien: Do you know how a general $su(2)$ generator $S^a_m$ acts on the state $|n\rangle$? You just need to act with $H$ on $|\psi\rangle$ and collect each basis elements $|n\rangle$ (potentially after shifting the summation index in some terms).

Comment: Yes I am confused about how to apply the spin operators to the basis vectors but after some more thought I think I made some progress, I posted it in the question as an edit.

Comment: @Julien: the states $|n\rangle$ are *not* eigenstates of the Hamiltonian, only $|\psi\rangle$ is. Since the states $|n\rangle$ and $|n\pm 1\rangle$ are orthogonal your "arbitrary $n$" equation can not be true unless $J=0$ and $E=E_0$. I also don't see how get the term $e^{2ik}|2\rangle>$ when acting with $H$ on $e^{ik}|1\rangle>$. How did the exponential change? $H$ doesn't depend on $k$.

Comment: Rather than writing the answer in the question itself, you can answer your own question. Looks better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I got it:
$$\langle \psi' | H| \psi\rangle =\sum_{n'=1}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\langle n'|e^{-ikn' }(-\frac{J}{2}\sum_{i=1}^NS_i^+S_{i+1}^-)\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{ikn}|n\rangle+\sum_{n'=1}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\langle n'|e^{-ikn' }(-\frac{J}{2}\sum_{i=1}^NS_i^-S_{i+1}^+)\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{ikn}|n\rangle +\sum_{n'=1}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\langle n'|e^{-ikn' }(-J\sum_{i=1}^NS_i^zS_{i+1}^z)\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{ikn}|n\rangle $$
Looking at each line of $\langle \psi' | H| \psi\rangle$ seperately:
$$\sum_{n'=1}^N\frac{-J}{2N}\langle n'|e^{-ikn' }(\sum_{i=1}^NS_i^+S_{i+1}^-)\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{ikn}|n\rangle=\frac{-J}{2N}\sum_{n'=1}^{N}\langle n'| (\sum_{i=1}^NS_i^+S_{i+1}^-)(e^{ik(1-n')}| 1\rangle + e^{ik(2-n')}| 2\rangle +...+e^{ik(N-n')}| N\rangle )$$
$$=\frac{-J}{2N}\sum_{n'=1}^N\langle n' |((e^{ik(1-n')}| 2\rangle+e^{ik(2-n')}| 3\rangle +...+e^{ik(N-n')}| 1\rangle) $$
$$=\frac{-J}{2}e^{-ik} $$
Following the same procedure for the second part I obtain:
$$\sum_{n'=1}^N\frac{-J}{2N}\langle n'|e^{-ikn' }(\sum_{i=1}^NS_i^-S_{i+1}^+)\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{ikn}|n\rangle =\frac{-J}{2N}\sum_{n'=1}^N \langle n' | (e^{ik(1-n')}| N \rangle+e^{ik(2-n')}| 1\rangle +...+e^{ik(N-n')}|N-1\rangle ) $$
$$=-\frac{J}{2}e^{ik}$$
Lastly:

$$\sum_{n'=1}^N\frac{1}{N}\langle n'|e^{-ikn' }(-J\sum_{i=1}^NS_i^zS_{i+1}^z)\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{ikn}|n\rangle =\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n'=1}^N\langle n' |(-J(\frac{-1}{4}+\frac{(N-2)}{4}-\frac{1}{4})e^{ik(1-n')}|1\rangle-J(-1+\frac{N}{4})e^{ik(2-n')}|2\rangle-J(-1+\frac{N}{4})e^{ik(N-n')}|N\rangle)$$
$$=J+E_o$$
Putting this all together I obtain:
$$E=-\frac{J}{2}e^{-ik}-\frac{J}{2}e^{ik}+J+E_o$$
$$E-E_o=J(1-cos(k))$$

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly more pedagogical approach that I would like to contribute which I feel is more intuitive. Long story short its provides the same Fourier transform but the spin flip terms feel more natural.

Suppose we have an $N$ site chain. Furthermore, suppose we have periodic boundary conditions. We can easily calculate the ferromagnetic energy exactly.

Start with the ferromagnetic state notice that only the ising terms contribute as spin exchange kills the state.

$$H|\uparrow \uparrow \cdots \rangle = -J \frac{N}{4}|\uparrow \uparrow \cdots \rangle$$

What about one spin flip on site $n$
$$|\uparrow_1 \uparrow_2 \cdots \uparrow_{n-1} \downarrow_n \uparrow_{n+1} \cdots \uparrow_N \rangle \equiv |n\rangle$$

What does the Hamiltonian do to this state? Notice that $(N-2)$ bonds are participating in ferromagnetic bonds and the exchange terms move the spin flip to the left and right and moreover you pay a diagonal penalty for antialigned spins for the two bonds $\frac{J}{4} +\frac{J}{4} = \frac{J}{2}$.

$$H|n\rangle = -J\frac{(N-2)}{4}|n\rangle - \frac{J}{2}|n-1\rangle -\frac{J}{2}|n+1\rangle +\frac{J}{2}|n\rangle$$

Now suppose we have a superposition of one spin flip

$$|\psi\rangle =\sum_n a_n |n\rangle$$

and let us assume that it is an eigenstate.

plug it in

$$H|\psi\rangle = \varepsilon |\psi\rangle$$
$$ H|\psi\rangle =-J\frac{(N-2)}{4}|\psi\rangle -\frac{J}{2}\sum_n a_n|n-1\rangle -\frac{J}{2}\sum_n a_n|n+1\rangle + \frac{J}{2}\sum_n a_n |n\rangle= \varepsilon \sum_n a_n |n\rangle $$
reindex the last two sums in the middle equation!

$$ H|\psi\rangle =-J\frac{(N-2)}{4}|\psi\rangle - \frac{J}{2}\sum_n a_{n+1}|n\rangle -\frac{J}{2}\sum_n a_{n-1}|n\rangle = \varepsilon \sum_n a_n |n\rangle$$

Inner product both equations with  $|m\rangle$.

$$-J\frac{(N-2)}{4}a_m- \frac{J}{2} a_{m+1} -\frac{J}{2} a_{m-1} +\frac{J}{2} a_m= \varepsilon  a_m $$

Now, since we have periodic boundary conditions.

$a_{n+L} = a_n $ which can be satisfied with $a_n = e^{i k n}$ and the appropriate choice of $k$.

$$-J\frac{(N-2)}{4}e^{ikm}- \frac{J}{2} e^{ikm+ik} -\frac{J}{2} e^{ikm-ik}+\frac{J}{2} e^{ikm} = \varepsilon  e^{ikm} $$

$$-J\frac{(N-2)}{4}- \frac{J}{2} e^{ik} -\frac{J}{2} e^{-ik} +\frac{J}{2} = \varepsilon   $$

$$-J\frac{N}{4} +\frac{J}{2}- J \cos k +\frac{J}{2}= \varepsilon   $$

$$\varepsilon_0 +J- J \cos k = \varepsilon   $$

$$ J(1-\cos k) = \varepsilon-\varepsilon_0   $$